# Javascript - How to escape double and single quotes on Kendo template

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui

I'm using kendolistview on my view page(razor). Inside of the kendo template I have this code. It just opens the bootstrap pop-up with. Problem is the "content" data has some " and ' values. So the link cannot be referred to the js function and the pop-up doesn't open.

I tried replacing the quotes in the data layer:

```
          Content = rss.CONTENT.Replace(@"\""", "\"").Replace("'", @"\'")
          Summary = rss.SUMMARY.Replace(@"\""", "\"").Replace("'", @"\'")
```

**View**

```
    @model AIS.UI.WebService.Proxy.DSrvAllService.NewsItem
    @using Kendo.Mvc.UI      

        @(Html.Kendo().ListView<AIS.UI.WebService.Proxy.DSrvAllService.NewsItem>()
  .Name("listView")
  .TagName("div")
  .ClientTemplateId("template")
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource        
     .Model(model =>model.Id("ID"))
     .ServerOperation(true)

     .PageSize(2)
    .Events(events => events.Error("onError"))             
    .Read(read => read.Action("GetNewsList", "News"))

    )
.Pageable()


)  



        <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
      ....
      <a                
   href="javascript:openNewsPopup('#:Title1#','#:Summary#','#:Content#','#:ImageURL#','#:AddTime#
  ','#:AddDate#','#:AddYear#','#:SubmitedBy#')" class="btn pull-right"><span style="font-  
   weight:normal" rel="tooltip" title="Read more about the announcement">Read More</span></a>

  <script>
```

Js(viewmodel)

```
var OpenNewsPopupViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.Title = ko.observable("");
    self.Summary = ko.observable("");
    self.Content = ko.observable("");
    self.ImageURL = ko.observable("");
    self.AddTime = ko.observable("");
    self.AddDate = ko.observable("");
    self.AddYear = ko.observable("");
    self.SubmitedBy = ko.observable("");
    self.ImageURLFull = ko.observable("");
};

  var openNewsPopupViewModel = null;

function openNewsPopup(pTitle, pSummary, pContent, pImageURL, pAddTime, pAddDate, pAddYear, pSubmitedBy) {


    var imageRootPath = '@Url.Content("~/Images/Announcements/NewsTypes/NewsType")';

    var isNewViewModel = (openNewsPopupViewModel == null);

    var newsPopup = $("#newsPopup");

    if (isNewViewModel) 
    {
        openNewsPopupViewModel = new OpenNewsPopupViewModel();

        var newsPopupTag = newsPopup.get()[0];
        ko.applyBindings(openNewsPopupViewModel, newsPopupTag);
    }

   // pContent = str.replace(/\"/g, "\\\"");
    openNewsPopupViewModel.Title(pTitle);
    openNewsPopupViewModel.Summary(pSummary);
    openNewsPopupViewModel.Content(pContent);
    openNewsPopupViewModel.ImageURL(pImageURL);
    openNewsPopupViewModel.AddTime(pAddTime);
    openNewsPopupViewModel.AddDate(pAddDate);
    openNewsPopupViewModel.AddYear(pAddYear);
    openNewsPopupViewModel.SubmitedBy(pSubmitedBy);
    openNewsPopupViewModel.ImageURLFull("");
    openNewsPopupViewModel.ImageURLFull(imageRootPath + '.' +  openNewsPopupViewModel.ImageURL() + '.jpg');


    newsPopup.modal('show');
}
```

Sample data(that should be replaced double quotes)

```
  <a href="javascript:openNewsPopup(' Version 1  is Released','Version 1.0 
   is now available on web. You can download the new version of the  
  client program from the website" http:="" 255.255.255.0="" test"="" or="" 
  installed="" program="" can="" automatically="" download="" it="" for="" 
  you.','news="" context="" will="" be="" placed="" here.="" news="" .="" 
  ','update','12:04',="" '01.01','2013','admin')"="" class="btn pull-right"><span 
  style="font-weight:normal" rel="tooltip" title="Read more about the 
  announcement">Read More</span></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to encode the strings before sending them down to the client. If setting the strings in a Razor view, you can simply call `@Html.Encode(string)`. To encode the content outside of a Razor view (e.g. in your data access code) just call [`System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) directly.

```
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("A simple 'encoded' \"string.\"");
// A simple &#39;encoded&#39; &quot;string.&quot;
```

Comment: And here is another problem and that is the # (sharp) isn't escaped for Kendo Template, which cause error in rendering.

Answer (score 2):

Each # symbol that is not part of a template expression— #: #, # # or #= # —must be escaped \#.

[Link to docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/templating/client-detail-template)

Comment: what if it's part of a variable `#:data.MyVar#`?